# Python: subset of list as equally distributed as possible?

Tags: python, list

I have a range of possible values, for example:

```
possible_values = range(100)
```

I have a list with unsystematic (but unique) numbers within that range, for example:

```
somelist = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 33, 77, 99]
```

I want to create a new list of length < len(somelist) including a subset of these values but as equally distributed as possible over the range of possible values. For example:

```
length_newlist = 2
newlist = some_function(somelist, length_newlist, possible_values)
print(newlist)
```

Which would then ideally output something like

```
[33, 77]
```

So I neither want a random sample nor a sample that chosen from equally spaced integers. I'd like to have a sample based on a distribution (here an uniform distribution) in regard to an interval of possible values.
Is there a function or an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: distributed based on value or on location in the list?

Comment: I mean in regard to the range of possible values. If possible values are from 0 to 100 but the list is skewed, for example [0,5,10,15,20,33,77,99] and I should choose two values, it would be [33,77] rather than [10,33] (which would be equally distributed across the indices). I edited my answer with this example so it is hopefully more clear what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the closest values of your subset to certain list's pivots? ie:

```
def some_function(somelist, length_list, possible_values):
    a = min(possible_values)
    b = max(possible_values)
    chunk_size = (b-a)/(length_list+1)

    new_list = []
    for i in range(1,length_list+1):
        index = a+i*chunk_size
        new_list.append(min(somelist, key=lambda x:abs(x-index)))

    return new_list

possible_values = range(100)
somelist = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 33, 77, 99]
length_newlist = 2
newlist = some_function(somelist, length_newlist, possible_values)

print(newlist)
```

In any case, I'd also recommend to take a look to [numpy's random sampling](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.random.html) functions, that could help you as well.

Comment: That is basically what I meant. Two caveats though (for me anyway...): the above code returns repeated values (so the selected items must be deleted from somelist) and the range is exceeded if the nearest value is above the range.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your range is 0..N-1, and you want a list of K<=N-1 values.  Then define an "ideal" list of K values, which would be your desired distribution over this full list (which I am frankly not sure I understand what that would be, but hopefully you do).  Finally, take the closest matches to those values from your randomly chosen greater-than-K-length sublist to get your properly distributed K-length random sublist.

Answer (score -2):

I think you should check `random.sample(population, k)` function. It samples the population in k-length list.

Comment: This has little to do with the question which asks for a very specific sample.

Comment: This seems to only select random values. I'd need a non-random selection based on a uniform distribution.

Comment: How can you select non-randomly basing on the distribution?

Comment: Maybe some randomness is necessary in some cases (I did not really think about that yet), but I mean values are not picked completely at random. The values in the resulting list should be the ones best reflecting a certain distribution, here a uniform distribution within a given interval / range.

Comment: Okay, I get it now. You pick a number from ` possible_values ` and search for closest value in ` somelist `, is that right?